# In a graph $G$, why can at most two vertices be adjacent to all of $E(G)$?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm going through a proof using this fact. I'm assuming the degree sum formula applies, but I still can't wrap my head around this fact.

Comment: I guess this claim is false when $E(G)$ is empty. In all other cases, pick any edge - then at most its end points can ..

Comment: How can three vertices be joined to one edge?